# Remove FreeDOS from ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have installed ubuntu alongside FreeDOS. Now that i think of it, i should've erased FreeDOS and do a clean ubuntu install.

[image: Here's the picture of my partitions from gparted]

I want to remove FreeDOS from my computer, but it has the boot flag. Can I remove FreeDOS entirely, or is it better to just shrink it down (if yes, to what size) ?

Comment: Are you using Grub installed to the MBR? If so, it's probably safe to just delete the FreeDOS partition. Windows usually has a boot flag also and I often delete Windows with no problems.

Comment: @mchid i havent checked if my disk is an mbr or a gpt, i will check tomorrow as its already night time. But as isee it, there are no other partitions, so the partition table is most likely inside the freedos partition. I wonder if i delete that partition, can windows make a new one and let me install grub into it?